# Запретить подгрузку стилей с других сайтов?

Tags: css

Всем доброго дня, установил виджет себе на сайт, всем доволен но по дизайну ну вообще не подходит, хотел изменить стили но не выходит, виджет подгружает их с другого ресурса, переопределить не выходит, js файлы также лежат на стороне разработчиков. Связался с ними, сказали что стили нельзя поменять пока что. Вопрос в следующем, можно как то запретить подгрузку стилей с их ресурсов? т.е. запрет определенного адреса что ли, тогда блоки по идее начнут слушаться моих стилей.

Comment: переопределяйте, создавая правило одним уровнем вложенности выше, чем у исходного стиля. Костыль, но будет работать.

Comment: если это виджет через айфрейм, то нет.